# SET doesn't update variable inside IF?

Tags: batch-file

Why c is 8 outside the if but is 0 after the same operation inside it? I'm using an ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION AT THE TOP. Am I missing something?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set a=5
set b=3

SET c=0
set /a c=5+3
echo. %a% %b% %c%

SET c=0
IF 2 GTR 0 (
set /a c=5+3
echo. %a% %b% %c%
)
```

Comment: try with `echo. !a! !b! !c!`

Comment: JosefZ that's about a subroutine. I ask why it does'nt work inside an IF in the same main batch,,,

Comment: And there is a big ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION at the top...

Comment: npocmaka i tried your answer and it worked. Thanks. I thought %var% and !var! were the same, I shouls ask a new question!